# How to dynamically allocate array and assign address to pointer defined in shared library using ctypes?

Tags: python, c, ctypes

My library is generated from simulink and looks like this:

**lib.h**

```
extern double *params1;
extern double *params2; 

typedef struct {
  unsigned int params1_len;
  unsigned int params2_len;
} P_model_T;
```

**lib.c**

```
double *params1;
double *params2;

P_model_T model_params = { 0, 0 };

void step(double in, double *out) {
  // some code using the parameter arrays
}
```

I intend to use it from python like this, with the assumption that `set_params` will always be called before calling the `step` function (thus initializing the needed parameter arrays):

**lib_wrapper.py**

```
from ctypes import *

import numpy as np

class LibWrapper:
  def __init__(self):
    self._library = CDLL("lib.dll")
    self._param_struct = ModelParameters.in_dll(self._library, 'model_params')

  def step(self, _in):
    out = c_double()
    self._library.step(c_double(_in), byref(out))
    return out

  def get_params(self, param_name):
    array_len = getattr(self._param_struct, f'{param_name}_len')  # get length of parameter array
    array_p = POINTER(c_double * array_len).in_dll(self._library, param_name)  # get actual array from library
    return np.array(array_p.contents)  # copy and return

  def set_params(self, param_name, data):
    array = (c_double * len(data))(*data)
    setattr(self._library, param_name, pointer(array))

class ModelParameters(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('params1_len', c_uint32),
                ('params2_len', c_uint32)]
```

My question is about the implementation of `set_params`: from what I understand my solution does not assign `array`'s address to my actual `params1`/`params2` variable in the dll, but it only changes the dll representation inside ctypes. Because of this I always get an access violation when calling my `step` function, as my parameter variables are still pointing to 0x0000000000000000.

**What would be the correct way to assign my allocated array to the `params` variables in the shared library?**

Follow-up: would there be a cleaner way to write my `get_params`? Can ctypes somehow "remember" the type of my `params` variables after I set them, so that I don't need to cast them?

Comment: I know only a little `python`, but all member functions in class `LibWrapper` have `self` as the first argument, _except_ for `step`. But, `step` uses `self`. Should `step` be: `def step(self,in):`?

Comment: Your structure has `unsigned int` parameters but your Python declaration has `c_double`.  Also `in` is a keyword so that Python code should give a SyntaxError.

Comment: @CraigEstey, MarkTolonen thanks, you are both right. 
I simplified my real code when writing the question, but didn't do a great job apparently :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work but it was a trick.  Your `set_params` wasn't looking up the parameter by `in_dll` so it wasn't effective.  Also, even with `in_dll` accessing contents just tried to dereference the null pointer already there, so I needed to get the address of the parameter to change the null pointer.  I used the following DLL and Python code to test:

test.c

```c
#define API __declspec(dllexport)

typedef struct {
  unsigned int params1_len;
  unsigned int params2_len;
} P_model_T;

API double *params1;
API double *params2;

API P_model_T model_params = { 0, 0 };

// For testing:
//   Increment params1 array by the "in" parameter.
//   Return the sum of the params2 array.
//
API void step(double in, double *out) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < model_params.params1_len; ++i)
        params1[i] += in;
    *out = 0.0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < model_params.params2_len; ++i)
        *out += params2[i];
}
```

test.py

```py
from ctypes import *

import numpy as np

class LibWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self._library = CDLL('test.dll')
        self._param_struct = ModelParameters.in_dll(self._library, 'model_params')
        self._library.step.argtypes = c_double,POINTER(c_double)
        self._library.step.restype = None

    def step(self, in_):
        out = c_double()
        self._library.step(in_, byref(out))
        return out.value

    def get_params(self, param_name):
        array_len = getattr(self._param_struct, f'{param_name}_len')  # get length of parameter array
        array_p = POINTER(c_double * array_len).in_dll(self._library, param_name)  # get actual array from library
        return np.array(array_p.contents)  # copy and return

    def set_params(self, param_name, data):
        array = (c_double * len(data))(*data)
        setattr(self,f'_{param_name}',array) # keep a reference since "array" will will free after return otherwise.
        array_p = POINTER(c_double).in_dll(self._library, param_name)  # get actual array from library
        array_pp = POINTER(POINTER(c_double)).from_address(addressof(array_p)) # get address of array pointer
        array_pp.contents = array # point it to the array
        setattr(self._param_struct, f'{param_name}_len', len(data)) # Update the parameter length

class ModelParameters(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('params1_len', c_int),
                ('params2_len', c_int)]

lib = LibWrapper()
lib.set_params('params1',[1.0,2.0,3.0])
lib.set_params('params2',[3.0,4.0,5.0])
print(lib.step(5))
print(lib.get_params('params1'))
print(lib.get_params('params2'))
```

Output:

```
12.0
[6. 7. 8.]
[3. 4. 5.]
```